# How can I show that for random variable $Z$ with Charateristic function $e^{-\vert t \vert+it}$, $E[\vert Z \vert]$ does not exist?

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

How can I show that for random variable $Z$ with Characteristic function $e^{-\vert t \vert+it}$, $E[\vert Z \vert]$ does not exist?
I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If $Z$ is integrable, then you may use Dominated Convergence Theorem to show that its characteristic function is differentiable at $t=0$.

Comment: So are you saying the expectation is well defined ?

Comment: It is actually the opposite. Note that your cf.f is not differentiable at $t=0$, hence $Z$ is not integrable. Alternatively, you can check that $Z$ has Cauchy distribution $\operatorname{Cauchy}(1,1)$, whose expectation is obviously not well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $E(|Z|)<\infty$. It is well-known that in that case, $\phi_Z$ must be differentiable at $0$.

However $\text{Re} (\phi_Z):t\mapsto e^{-|t|}\cos(t)$ is not differentiable at $0$, a contradiction.